# How to use npm package with Oracle APEX on Cloud?

Tags: javascript, npm, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX 20.2 on Oracle Cloud.

I trying to integrate project from github with Oracle APEX.

Project: https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-auto-layout

It looks like I need npm to install.

How can I integrate that project with Oracle APEX?